# Get by name in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Instead of using get_by_id() method for getting the id of a specific entry and print the content of this entry from the google datastore,  i am trying to get the name of the url and print the content. For example:

```
<a href="http://.../name"></a>
```

print all the content that have this specific name(may have more than one rows of content with this name)

```
<a href="http://.../343532432"></a>
```

print the content of the specific id

i am using get_by_id(long(id)) to get the id in the second part of my example, and its working. I am trying to use get_by_key_name(name) but it does not working. any ideas on that? thank you.

sorry, but since i couldn't leave a comment, i am editing my question. Basically, since now i can get all the name of animals from my datastore and i have made them clickable using an html code in template file. In the datastore, there are entries with the same name of animal more than one times (e.g. name= duck, content= water and name=duck, content=lake). Now, when i am clicking into every name of animals(i have use the DINSTINCT in my gql query to print redundant elements(e.g. duck) only one time).Since the name=duck has two contents, when i am clicking on the name of the duck i want to see both of the contents. My problem is if i am using get_by_id(long(id)) i get the unique id of every element. But this will not print me both of the content of the name=duck because every entry has a unique id. But i want all the content of the entries with the same name. I am trying the following but it does not working.

```
     msg = MODEL.Animals.get_by_key_name(name)
     self.response.write("%s" % msg.content)
```

Comment: Hard to diagnose what the issue is without more details.

Comment: Your data may have integer ID, or string KEY name. Both you can get by  using get_by_id(). Try something like get_by_id('name'), or provide more info so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

With get_by_id() you can get entity only if you know this ID. This operations named "Small operations" in quota and they are cheaper than datastore reads, but to get list of entities filtered by indexed property - you should use filters.

```
query = MODEL.Animals.query()
query = query.filter(MODEL.Animals.name == 'duck')
ducks = query.fetch(limit=100)  # limit number of returned animals
for duck in ducks:
   self.response.write('%s - %s' % (duck.name, duck.content))
```

By default, all string properties are indexed, so you will be able to do such requests.